# File validation API Failing in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am trying File validation API in Jmeter but it is failing, Please help me to get overcome this issue.

Please see images for Jmeter request and header manager
[Http Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZS1B.png)[][Header]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciNPh.png)
Thanks
Raghavendra

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the [API contract](https://lazaroibanez.com/development-what-is-an-api-contract-683ced58e06f?gi=6a4c3d4a74b5) we cannot help you in fixing the request.

One thing is obvious: if you're sending the file it needs to go to the Files Upload tab of the HTTP Request sampler. Also tick `User multupart/form-data` box:

[image]

If you can execute the request using your browser or API testing tool like [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/) or [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) you can just record the request using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html), just make sure to copy the file to JMeter's "bin" folder prior to executing the request, this way JMeter will be able to catch it and generate HTTP Request sampler and HTTP Header Manager. More information: [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter)